# Assigning value in array in foreach loop error

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a [CSV file](http://euryalosstudios.com/api/3.csv) which I am trying to parse into an array using PHP. Here is my code:

```
<?php 

echo "hi";
$csvData = file_get_contents('2.csv');
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
$x=0;
foreach ($lines as $line) { 
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
    $x=$x+1;
}
echo $x;
print_r($array);


echo "<font size=\"10\" color=\"green\">DONE</font>";
?>
```

When I ran this script I was getting a blank page with no error. So I added and print out statement "hi". So now when I run this script I only get "hi"

I did some troubleshooting and I found out that this line

```
$array[] = str_getcsv($line);
```

Specifically the `$array[]` is giving me the problem.  Here is a link of the script in action

http://euryalosstudios.com/api/new1.php

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your php code ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($lines)` give you? May be there is no value in `$lines` ?

Comment: Also, I am not sure if your CSV file is actually comma separated. Maybe you are using a `;` as a separator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `fgetcsv` instead of exploding on `PHP_EOL` file contents. e.g.:

```
$fh = fopen('2.csv', "r");
$lines = array();
while ($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    $lines[] = $row;
}
echo count($lines);
print_r($lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

your file 2.csv is 20MB, probably you are hitting php memory limit like so

```
2015/05/08 00:22:49 [error] 7202#0: *1164289 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11 bytes) in /var/www/xxxxxx.com/so/go.php on line 10" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: www.xxxxxx.com, request: "GET /so/go.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxxxxx.com", referrer: "http://xxxxxx.com/so/"
```

I'm getting this error on my server.

Answer (score 0):

At first, check your php version, because str_getcsv available from php 5.3.0
At second add few lines

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

and show output